# How to get element's data in following xml code using ElementTree in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<Network id="5-Bus Test System" BaseKVAvalue="l00" unit="mva">
<BusList defaultBaseV="13800" unit="volt"> 
<Bus id="l" type="pq"> 
<P value="l.6" unit="pu"/> 
<Q value="0.8" unit="pu"/> </Bus> 
</BusList> 
</Network>
```

what command should we use to get the bus's element data i.e P ,Q values to print as output

I tried this 2 statements to extract the data

```
print(root[0][0]).text  and print(root[0][0]).tail
```

but it is giving none as output for both

for the below statement output is giving only its attribute but not data

```
print(root[0][0]).attrib
```

ouptut is {'type': 'pq', 'id': 'l'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer looking up nodes by name. The following is one way to retrieve the attributes of the `P` and `Q` elements:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("network.xml")

print tree.find("BusList/Bus/P").attrib
print tree.find("BusList/Bus/Q").attrib
```

Output:

```
{'unit': 'pu', 'value': 'l.6'}
{'unit': 'pu', 'value': '0.8'}
```

But if you want to access the nodes by index, you can do it like so:

```
root = tree.getroot()
print root[0][0][0].attrib
print root[0][0][1].attrib
```

Comment: thanks i don't know that there is a option of like this, got it!!